# Why do I get this error when I create a phone gap application in command line

Tags: windows, cordova, command-line

[image]

I keep getting this error when I try to create a phone gap application in the Windows command line.

I have nodejs installed.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
phonegap create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

Try this command.